# How to create google contacts using People API and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-api-js-client, google-people-api

Im searching for how to create google contacts using the `People API`, i have followed the guide here:

https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/nodejs

My current code:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Tasks API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listConnectionNames);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Print the display name if available for 10 connections.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listConnectionNames(auth) {
  const service = google.people({version: 'v1', auth});
  service.people.connections.list({
    resourceName: 'people/me',
    pageSize: 2,
    personFields: 'names,emailAddresses',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.error('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const connections = res.data.connections;
    if (connections) {
      console.log('Connections:');
      connections.forEach((person) => {
        if (person.names && person.names.length > 0) {
          console.log(person.names[0].displayName);
        } else {
          console.log('No display name found for connection.');
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No connections found.');
    }
  });

  service.people.createContact({
    requestBody: {
      emailAddresses: [{value: 'test@test.com'}],
      names: [
        {
          displayName: 'A',
          familyName: 'B',
          givenName: 'C',
        },
      ],
    },
  });
  //console.log('\n\nCreated Contact:', newContact);

}
```

I succeed in `reading` my contacts and in creating the OAuth authentication key.

https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact
(Sadly this link doesn't have a full working example like on the link to read contacts)

I tried to create a contact adding this code:

```js
  service.people.createContact({
    requestBody: {
      emailAddresses: [{value: 'test@test.com'}],
      names: [
        {
          displayName: 'A',
          familyName: 'B',
          givenName: 'C',
        },
      ],
    },
  });
```

But, when i add the code, it return an error:

```
(node:8392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Insufficient Permission
    at Gaxios.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Desktop\Nova pasta\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:73:27)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\Desktop\Nova pasta\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:16:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8392) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error: Insufficient Permission

Means that you are trying to do something that you dont have permission to do.

The create method requires that you have authorized the user with the following scope

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts

I suspect that you have have changed the scope in your code and not reauthorized your user.

- delete token.json,
- Have the user go to [permissions](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) find your app and remove its access. then try to run your application again.

Comment: Thank you Linda, perdon for the tweet, i deleted the token and authenticate again and it did work.

Comment: If there was a tweet i missed it :)  Happy you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your questions in the same order that you formulate them:

1. *In the file `credentials.json` (from first link), it contains a `clientID` is this `clientID` that will be used on `'clientId':'`?*

Yes, the [`clientId`](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-api-key) is one part of the OAuth 2.0 protocol.

2. *Does `scope` value changes or will be the same ever?*

The script scope should only change when you need it. Ideally, you would use the most restrictive scope unless you need a less limited one. [Here](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing) there is a list of valid People API scopes.

3. *Whats wrong with the error `ReferenceError: gapi is not defined`*

This error warns you that the `gapi` variable hasn't been declared. The original code shared by @ChavdaMadhav is not a complete example. You would need to fill in the blanks to make it run, and that includes the definition of the `gapi` variable. Please, don't hesitate to write back if you have doubts on this answer or the other ones.

Comment: Jacques i rewrite my current code and edited the topic, im still could not get how to create a contact, could you take a look?