# OAuth Google People API refresh token does not work for contacts scope in python

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-people-api

I get access and refresh token using oauth and the following scopes:

```
const scopes = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.other.readonly",
];
```

Before I only used the calendar scope and everything worked before and after the access token expired. When I integrated the contacts and other contacts scope I'm able to get the access token and refresh token and make successful requests to the calendar and people API.

But now (with the contacts scopes) after the access token expires, I get this error:

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:searchContacts?pageSize=5&query=sofia&readMask=names%2CemailAddresses&alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'method': 'google.people.v1.PeopleService.SearchContacts', 'service': 'people.googleapis.com'}}]">
```

In my python logic the tokens are actually refreshed. The 'got to after refresh' print is printed and also 'CREDS AND ACCESS TOKEN WERE UPDATED on host' that is printed after an update in the db.

```
creds = get_google_creds_simple_helper(google_calendar_tokens)
print(creds.valid, 'creds.valid')

if not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        print('got to BEFORE REFRESH')
        try:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error refreshing credentials:', e)
        print('got to after refresh')
        google_calendar_tokens["token"] = creds.token
        host.google_calendar_tokens = google_calendar_tokens
        host.save()
        print('CREDS AND ACCESS TOKEN WERE UPDATED on host')
return creds
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Which method are you using? Based on the error I understand that you're trying to use [`Method: people.searchContacts`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchContacts), can you try adding this other scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts` and go through the authorization flow again to make sure you get a new access token with the correct scopes authorized.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you solved this already, but I encountered the same problem.
For me deleting the access token as mentioned in the following solution worked.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65336629

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35602858)